# Redirect visitors based on current URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, refresh

Is there a way to redirect my visitors using **PHP** by copying the current URL they are using and adding **/fr** to it so that it keeps redirecting them on all pages to the **French** version of my website? the reason why i need it to be in **PHP** is that i need to add an if statement to the code.

examples:-

mywebsite.com/home

TO

mywebsite.com/home/**fr**

---

mywebsite.com/blog

TO

mywebsite.com/blog/**fr**

---

mywebsite.com/login

TO

mywebsite.com/login/**fr**

Comment: assuming your url structure will be consistent you could get the url using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` , then use `$var = explode('/' $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` then use `$last = end($var);` then `if($last != "fr") { }

Answer (score 0):

You can have an idea,

```
$currentUrl = "mywebsite.com/home";

$newUrl = $currentUrl . "/fr";

header("Location:$newUrl");
```